# Send message from background script to content script then response in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension.  My background script fires on a button press in the ui.  It should send a message to my content script, which is going to send a response back to the background script.  Can't quite figure out how this is supposed to work.  The click listener is firing, but the messaging does not work.  Here is what I got so far:

Background Script:

```
$(document).on('click', '#getGlobalFuncsBtn', function(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({text:"getStuff"},function(reponse){       
        if(reponse.type == "test"){
            console.log('test received');
        }
    });
    console.log('click listener');
});
```

Content Script:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    if(message.text == "getStuff"){
        console.log('test sent');
        sendResponse({type:"test"});
    }
});
```

Popup HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button id="getGlobalFuncsBtn">Get Global Funcs</button>

<script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Var Viewer",
  "description": "This extension allows you to view and change all user defined js global vars.",
  "version": "1.1",
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.0.2.min.js","content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "jquery-2.0.2.min.js"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "pop.html",
    "default_title": "Var Viewer"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) First of all, you are trying to trigger `getGlobalFuncsBtn` button click event inside background script, which is pointless. Actually, you are declaring `background.js` two times: first time inside `manifest` file:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","background.js"]
},
```

(**which means it is a background script**)

, second time inside popup.html:

```
<script src="background.js"></script>
```

(**which means it is a popup JavaScript file**)

`Background page` is a place where you only perform some background actions (for example, calculations). `popup.html` is your actual popup window, so that is a place when you should work with button using jQuery. Overall, you should just erase `background` field in manifest.json (and it would be great to rename `background.js` to something like `popup.js`, but it is not necessary).

(Your background script fires on a button press because you declared it once properly - inside `popup.html`.)

You can read more about `background pages` in the official documentation: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html.

2) Your second problem is with the message sending between extension page (it could be any extension page, in your code snippets it is `background.js`) and `content script`. If you want to set communication channel between two regular extension pages, it is pretty straightforward. Use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`. However, if you want to communicate with `content script`, you have to use slightly more complicated by defining the particular `tab` you are sending message to (`content script` is actually executed as a part of the code of tab you specified in `manifest` file). You code should be something like this:

in `background.js` (or `popup.js` if you rename it):

```
// code below is supposed to be inside your button trigger
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {text:"getStuff"}, function(response) {
    if(response.type == "test"){
      console.log('test received');
    }
  });
});
```

`Content script` event listener looks the same for `extension page` or `content script`, so your `content.js` code should work properly as it is. You only need to replace `extension` with `runtime`:

in `content.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.text == "getStuff") {
      console.log('test sent');
      sendResponse({type: "test"});
    }
});
```

Nice read about the message passing in `Chrome extension`: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html.

Comment: I think everything you pointed out should be correct minus one thing. I guess I needed to list content.js inside the web_accessible_resources of the manifest file. If it's not listed in there it can't be used as a content script. I have tried the runtime.onMessage and the tabs.query before it just never worked due to this fact. Thanks for the help though I didn't know that about injecting the bg script twice. Cheers. :)

Comment: I also just found out that the popup script gets refreshed (if you make changes to it) simply by reopening the popup (assuming youve made changes to it and saved it and have loaded it as an unpacked extesion), but the content script only gets refreshed by re installing the extension.  The "update extensions" button does not actually update it.

Comment: @carter Yes, you are right. `Content script` is actually running separately from the extension. It is closer to the tabs' code than extension files, so you need to reload extension in order to force `content script` code changes to be applied.